# OpenGL 4+ drawing a 2D grid like maya/max

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I'm trying to draw a grid like Maya/max/modo/etc in opengl 4.4 in C++. I found one tutorial on how to do this - [LINK](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Scientific_OpenGL_Tutorial_04#Drawing_a_grid) it doesn't work with my framework - which is creating my VBOs, then doing input, and camera handling, and then rendering everything with abj_render().

The problem here is that this only draws a grid with horizontal and vertical lines *if* glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) is written into the createVBO() function. If I have glClear in the regular spot it only draws horizontal or vertical lines - not both.

Is it correct to assume that abj_Render is currently in the right spot and that I should be clearing the screen only once per loop - within the rendering function and not in the VBO area? If so, how can this grid work correctly within this framework?

```
//MAIN
createVBO();
SDL_mainLoop();

void SDL_mainLoop()
{
    while (!quit)
    { 
        //CAMERA + MOVEMENT CONTROLS 
        abj_render();
    }
}

void createVBO()
{
    glGetError();

    struct point
    {
        GLfloat x;
        GLfloat y;
    };

    GLint gridLines = 20;
    float gridMinus = gridLines / 2;
    point Vertices[20][20];

    for (int i = 0; i < gridLines; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridLines; j++)
        {
            Vertices[i][j].x = (i - gridMinus) / gridMinus;
            Vertices[i][j].y = (j - gridMinus) / gridMinus;
        }
    }

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    programID = LoadShaders("simpleVertex.glsl", "simpleFragment.glsl");
    glUseProgram(programID);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // HAVING THIS *HERE* DRAWS GRID CORRECTLY

    glLineWidth((GLfloat)2.5f);

    if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
        abj_handleError(" Could not create a VBO", "gl");
}


void abj_render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); /// HAVING THIS *HERE* REMOVES THE VERTICALS
    glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);

    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    //GLint gridLines = 20;
    //int sizeOf(point) = 8;

    /////////// DRAW THE GRID ///////////
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 20 * i, 20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20 * 8, (void *)(i * 8));
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 20);
    }

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(gWindow);
}
```

The old style from old tutorials is like this:

```
// draw grid
glBegin(GL_LINES);
for (int i=-10;i<=10;++i)
{
    glVertex3f(i,0,-10);
    glVertex3f(i,0,10);

    glVertex3f(10,0,i);
    glVertex3f(-10,0,i);
}
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

Comment: You know that if you call this `abj_render (...)` function multiple times, every call after the first has somewhat unusual behavior. The first loop uses the attrib pointer you setup on the last iteration of the second loop (from the previous call); while this could be intentional, I doubt it. For consistency, you should probably call `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);` before the first loop or use VAOs the way they were intended (e.g. do not keep changing the pointer, just bind a different VAO).